# asp.net mvc windows azure migration System.BadImageFormatException: Could not load file or assembly 'Interop.SSCE' or

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, azure

Hi have follows the steps here

[Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/jnak/migrating-an-existing-asp-net-app-to-run-on-windows-azure)

to migrate an asp.net mvc project to windows azure, The project builds ok, I then hit f5 and I get the error above. Does any one have any ideas why this is happening? I am new to azure so Im not too familiar with the process, Any ideas would be appreciated thanks

Stack Trace

## === Pre-bind state information ===
LOG: User = IP-0AE2B2DF\Administrator
LOG: DisplayName = Interop.SSCE
(Partial)
LOG: Appbase = file:///C:/Users/Administrator/Documents/Visual Studio 2010/Projects/TestProject/src/TestProjectCloudService/bin/Release/TestProjectCloudService.csx/roles/TestProject.Web/approot/
LOG: Initial PrivatePath = C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\TestProject\src\TestProjectCloudService\bin\Release\TestProjectCloudService.csx\roles\TestProject.Web\approot\bin
Calling assembly : (Unknown).

LOG: This bind starts in default load context.
LOG: Using application configuration file: C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\TestProject\src\TestProjectCloudService\bin\Release\TestProjectCloudService.csx\roles\TestProject.Web\approot\web.config
LOG: Using host configuration file: C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v2.0.50727\Aspnet.config
LOG: Using machine configuration file from C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v2.0.50727\config\machine.config.
LOG: Policy not being applied to reference at this time (private, custom, partial, or location-based assembly bind).
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Users/Administrator/AppData/Local/dftmp/s0/deployment(3)/res/deployment(3).TestProjectCloudService.TestProject.Web.0/aspNetTemp/aspNetTemp/root/7dd3ee0f/d7fb43c0/Interop.SSCE.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Users/Administrator/AppData/Local/dftmp/s0/deployment(3)/res/deployment(3).TestProjectCloudService.TestProject.Web.0/aspNetTemp/aspNetTemp/root/7dd3ee0f/d7fb43c0/Interop.SSCE/Interop.SSCE.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Users/Administrator/Documents/Visual Studio 2010/Projects/TestProject/src/TestProjectCloudService/bin/Release/TestProjectCloudService.csx/roles/TestProject.Web/approot/bin/Interop.SSCE.DLL.
ERR: Failed to complete setup of assembly (hr = 0x8007000b). Probing terminated.

Answer (score 2):

Fixed, just removed reference to the web role project duh!